# object_label_method for associations in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Is there a way to specify the text shown in the selection box of an association in rails_admin?

I'm aware I can modify `object_label_method` for the whole model, but I want to show something different when selecting and only when selecting an association.

Comment: If you define it with the `object_label_method` where will you see the label wrong?

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba: on the title when editing or seeing the model, or list or shows when it shows the association. I only need it on edit (to differentiate several that have the same name).